# Symfony - Twig - Hypertext link that modifies or deletes a resource and returns a page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a website with Symfony/Twig that lists active issues on a page. Each issue has an "Accept" link next to its title. The "Accept" link is a hypertext link linking to a route containing the identifier of the issue (for instance: `/issues/{id}/accept`). When the link is clicked, the `accept` Symfony action is called. This Symfony action simply changes the status of the issue from "New" to "Accept" and redirects to the current page.

Everything works well.

My only problem is: the href link uses the GET method and modifies the issue resource at the server side. GET should not modify a resource. I may face the same problem for a "Remove" link, that would use a GET method (hyperlink) to call a Symfony action that deletes the resource.

In my case, is it okay to use a hyperlink (GET method) to modify/remove a resource or am I required to try to use the POST method instead (with a form) or implementing some JavaScript and then use PUT or PATCH ? Is there any simple way to prevent that problem only using Symfony and Twig (without JS) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don''t need to use JavaScript to use `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` methods without JavaScript in Symfony. Just use a regular HTML-form.

There's a configuration-option [`http_method_override`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#http-method-override) that allows you to set the HTTP method to i.e. `DELETE` on a form as follows.

In a Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('target_route'), 'method': 'DELETE'}) }}
```

During creation in a controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('target_route'),
    'method' => 'DELETE',
]);
```

Read more about this in the documentation chapter: [Changingg the Action and HTTP Method](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method)

Comment: +1
And the form also gives you nice CSRF protection. Just make sure that you handle the form before doing your action. Don' t just call your repository